# What is the time complexity for Immutable.JS's deleteIn?

Tags: immutable.js

Just curious, what is the time complexity for Immutable.JS's deleteIn? In the documentation, it says that `gets` and `sets` are O(log32 N) for immutable.Map. Assume that we are not deleting from an array, and the path length is P, I assume deleteIn would be O(P log32 N)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `O(P log32 N)`. All the `xIn` mutators simply perform an action at a given location and then recursively update the collections along the path, back to the root.